# How to pass data from FlexCard to Omniscript?

Tags: lightning-web-components, vlocity, omnistudio

I have an Omniscript with a FlexCard (custom LWC) inside. How could I get data from this FlexCard to the Omniscript?

I didn't find any doc about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow the steps of these articles: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_update_an_omniscript_from_a_flexcard_27677.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_download_a_sample_update_omniscript_action_datapack_27756.htm&type=5

1. FlexCard Designer
2. Action
3. **Update OmniScript** from the **Action Type** dropdown

**FlexCard**
[image]

**Omniscript**

The FlexCard is inside "FlexCardContainer"

*hasInvalidProduct* is a boolean, but the Omniscript is receiving like a string. So I had to add this formula to convert String to boolean.

[image]